# Building wheel for numpy (setup.py) ... error, Installing numpy==1.11.2

Tags: python, numpy, pip, python-wheel

I want to install https://github.com/scilus/ismrm_2015_tractography_challenge_scoring, but installing the requirements.txt file with pip (22.0.4) in Ubuntu isn't successful. When I run it, I get the following error message:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy, scipy, nibabel, Cython, dipy
  Building wheel for numpy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kaasupls/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kaasupls/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-6ftha8iz
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-kaasupls/numpy/
  Complete output (2482 lines):
  Running from numpy source directory.
  /tmp/pip-install-kaasupls/numpy/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py:452: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
    return is_string(s) and ('*' in s or '?' is s)
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
    NOT AVAILABLE
...
```

When I then run the same again, I get a new error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/home/ella/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1439, in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

I tried it within a virtual environment and from the Windows command line as well, but received similar errors.
Does anyone have an idea how to resolve these errors? I can also provide more lines of the error message of course, but didn't really know what part of it would be most relevant.

Comment: The requirements file pins specific versions of all packages, so the packages are being built by pip. Make sure, at least, that you have the Python development packages like `python3-dev`. As it will build scipy as well (probably), you need a Fortran compiler and all. You might want to relax the version constraint from the requirements file as an alternative.

Comment: Try installing *Python 3.5*, and use that one